# Config vars in apache environment vars

Tags: php, apache, system-administration

I'm running a few different PHP shopping carts at work and we're trying to get the various config files under version control. Up to this point we've just been ignoring them in git because, of course, we don't want production level passwords to be available to just anyone. Besides, most of us developers are running local installs with unique information.

While talking to our sysadmin about the problem I suddenly remember that we could set environment variables in the apache vhost block and access them from PHP, like so:

Apache: `SetEnv db_user "username"`

PHP: `<?php $config['db']['user'] = $_ENV['db_user'];`

It seems like it would work without a problem, but I've never seen it done like this before. Are there any implications (technical, security, etc) or limitations in handling authentication info this way?

Comment: Environment vars are widely used for distinguishing between application environments (e.g. production vs staging vs development); I don't see a downside to keeping the actual DB credentials there if you are not comfortable with the people who have access to the git repository, but it's interesting to see more answers here. And you should probably be using `$_ENV` and not `$_SERVER` in this case.

Comment: You're right, @lanzz, $_ENV is a better way of accessing the data I want. Thanks!

Comment: Heroku use this approach out of the box for Facebook apps (storing app Id and secret key). It also makes your code more portable as your important details aren't baked into your source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite close to something that is proposed in [the PHP Security Guide: Databases and SQL](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/3.html).

They note that one potential issue is a risk of exposing the variable via a call to "something like phpinfo() or print_r($_SERVER)." So the question is whether you can control that risk - and whether you trust everyone who gets access to that vhost (in your context, the answer to that is likely to be "yes").

They also propose adding an extra level of redirection by putting these credentials in a file readable only by root - which seems reasonable in deployment, if slightly paranoid in a development context.

Comment: You could (and probably should) unset the environment vars after the connection is established and you no longer need the credentials.